# Почему при этих вызовах функция не возвращает нужные значения?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, filter

Нужно,что бы функция оставляла только те объекты из  передаваемого ей массива,свойства которых соответствуют свойствам  объекта source(второй аргумент)

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {

  var arr = [];
  // Only change code below this line

arr=collection.filter((elem)=>{for(let i in source){
  return source[i]==elem[i]?true:false}});

    return arr;
}

whatIsInAName([{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }], { "apple": 1, "cookie": 2 }); // should return [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }].
whatIsInAName([{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }, { "bat":2 }], { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 });// should return [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie":2 }].
whatIsInAName([{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}], {"a": 1, "b": 9999, "c": 3});// should return []
```

Comment: надо проверять не равность, а разность. У вас сейчас если первые св-ва равны, то сразу вернется `true`, даже если остальные не равны

Comment: так это мне тогда в двух циклах перебирать   каждый объект коллекции и объект source?А потом сравнивать их свойства?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*цитирую сам себя* :D

> надо проверять не равность, а разность. У вас сейчас если первые св-ва равны, то сразу вернется true, даже если остальные не равны

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {

  return collection.filter((elem)=>{
    for(let i in source){
      if (source[i] !== elem[i]) {
        return false
      }
    }

    return true;
  });
}

const a = whatIsInAName([
  { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 },
  { "apple": 1 },
  { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }],
  { "apple": 1, "cookie": 2 });
// should return [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }].
console.log(a)
const b = whatIsInAName([
  { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 },
  { "apple": 1 },
  { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 },
  { "bat":2 }],
  { "apple": 1, "bat": 2 });
// should return [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie":2 }].
console.log(b)
const c = whatIsInAName([
  {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}],
  {"a": 1, "b": 9999, "c": 3});
// should return []
console.log(c)
```

Для пущей правды, можно добавить `hasOwnProperty` ( но это если совсем строгая проверка нужна )

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в использовании return без условия внутри цикла. Всегда будет выполняться только одна итерация. Чтобы избегать таких ошибок можно воспользоваться [методом `Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), чтобы получить список ключей и значений объекта, и с помощью метода [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) проверить что значения соответствуют:

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {

  return collection.filter((elem) => Object.entries(source).every(([key, val]) => elem[key] === val));
}

const a = whatIsInAName([{
    "apple": 1,
    "bat": 2
  },
  {
    "apple": 1
  },
  {
    "apple": 1,
    "bat": 2,
    "cookie": 2
  }
], {
  "apple": 1,
  "cookie": 2
});
// should return [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie": 2 }].
console.log(a)
const b = whatIsInAName([{
    "apple": 1,
    "bat": 2
  },
  {
    "apple": 1
  },
  {
    "apple": 1,
    "bat": 2,
    "cookie": 2
  },
  {
    "bat": 2
  }
], {
  "apple": 1,
  "bat": 2
});
// should return [{ "apple": 1, "bat": 2 }, { "apple": 1, "bat": 2, "cookie":2 }].
console.log(b)
const c = whatIsInAName([{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
  "c": 3
}], {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 9999,
  "c": 3
});
// should return []
console.log(c)
```

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl, у тебя в коде больше нет циклов

Comment: а это касается только объектов?

Comment: @ZdraviSmisl, не понял вопрос

Comment: да,чушь спросил..